# Keyboard shortcut for Spotlight doesn't work in full screen Google Chrome on Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: macos, keyboard, spotlight, google-chrome, fullscreen

I've noticed that the Spotlight Search keyboard shortcut (cmd space) doesn't work if I'm running Google Chrome (12.0.742.122) as full screen application in Lion.

Is this a Chrome-related bug or is this inherent of some type of applications? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: reproduced on 10.6.8. problem seems to lie with chrome though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be resolved in newer Chrome versions.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't currently support Lion's full screen features. They are [working on a version that does](http://chromeossite.com/2011/07/25/chrome-for-os-x-lion-in-the-making/).

Until that is finished, you'll have to use Chrome's built-in full screen capabilities (not based on Lion's).

You can change the keyboard shortcut to enter that the same way you'd change any other (System Preferences-> Keyboard-> Keyboard Shortctus-> [+] button

Answer (score 0):

No such problem with Safari (just tried it). the way to fix it: just switch to safari :P it's the same webkit rendering engine as chrome (meaning it's the same speed) and now it's a whole lot nicer with some of the new lion features

Comment: Actually, Chrome uses many technologies that make it faster than Safari. People have reasons they use the browser they do. I don't think this really answers the question.

Comment: to each his own

Comment: One word: Safari misses Chrome's Omnibox. It's a dealbreaker for me (among other things).